# CakePHP cakebake on linux

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-bake

Can Any Body Suggest me how to bake the cake in CakePHP 2.x on linux

What I have tried

```
$ cd MyProject/app/Console 
$ ./cake bake
```

it give me this line, don't know how to proceed from here

```
Welcome to CakePHP v2.1.3 Console
---------------------------------------------------------------
App : Console
Path: /var/www/MyProject/app/Console/
---------------------------------------------------------------
What is the path to the project you want to bake?  
[/var/www/MyProject/app/Console/myapp] >
```

Comment: For Windows and for Cake2 we need to adjust the project path like so:
C:\...\project\lib\Cake\Console

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### You're in the wrong path

When you do this:

```
$ cd /MyProject/app/Console
$ ./cake bake
```

You're launching the cake cli from inside the `Console` folder. That's not the right/normal way to execute the cake cli.

As is evident from the output, the cli thinks that you want to bake a new project *in* the `Console` folder because the path you are in, is not itself already a project. This [changed some months ago](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/commit/967526540a5f0a92e6c28fdbe5e7f8601dc30b5e), but in the version of cake you're using, the directory you are in, is assumed to be your app folder.

That said, ordinarily cake is used like this:

```
$ cd /MyProject/app
$ Console/cake bake

Welcome to CakePHP v2.3.6 Console
---------------------------------------------------------------
App : app
Path /var/www/project/app/
---------------------------------------------------------------
Interactive Bake Shell
---------------------------------------------------------------
[D]atabase Configuration
[M]odel
[V]iew
[C]ontroller
[P]roject
[F]ixture
[T]est case
[Q]uit
What would you like to Bake? (D/M/V/C/P/F/T/Q)
```

When already in an app folder - the bake command asks you what you want to create.